# Android WebView make fit to the screen and show loader

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

In my case of loading the URL of web view, I need the view to be fixed and also not scroll as above this webview i used to hold another view on top to perform some marker(Like freehand sketching) based actions, below is my code for the rendering of web view

```
binding.presentationWebView.apply {
        webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        setInitialScale(1)
        isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
        settings.apply {
            minimumFontSize = 10
            textZoom = 100
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            allowFileAccess = true
            allowContentAccess = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = false

        }
        addJavascriptInterface(PresentationJSInterface(), "Android")
        Timber.tag("PPT_NAVIGATION").d("inside PPT screen:")
        loadUrl(PRESENTATION_WRAPPER_URL)
    }
```

Now my adding the property "setInitialScale(1)" my view is fixed but, i don't see a loader when the web view is loaded or if there is any issue in rendering I can't see the loader which leaves the page as grey out, hence I need a loader in there without the view been scrollable. By making the "setInitialScale" property as 100 or above some 50 range i can see loader but user can able to scroll the view as the view is not fixed and has scroll in the webview,
Can some one sort this out like i need a fixed webview also a loader to be seen on the URL rendering , also user wont able to scroll